# Type Error: expected expression of type (string * terme) list, but received expression of type ((terme -> terme) * (terme -> terme)) list

Tags: ocaml

I've encountered this error and couldn't solve it.

```
type terme =
  | Var of string
  | Sym of string
  | Func of terme * terme

exception Echec

let rec sub v t = function 
  | Var v' when v = v' -> t
  | Func (t1, t2) -> Func (sub v t t1, sub v t t2)
  | t -> t

let rec occ_check v = function
  | Var v' when v'=v -> true
  | Func (t1,t2) -> occ_check v t1 || occ_check v t2
  | _ -> false

let rec unif e (t1, t2) =
  match (t1, t2) with
  | Var v1, Var v2 when v1 = v2 -> e
  | Var v, t | t, Var v ->
      if List.mem_assoc v e then unif e (List.assoc v e, t)
      else if occ_check v t then raise Echec
      else (v, t) :: List.map (fun (t1, t2) -> (sub v t1, sub v t2)) e
  | Func (f1, a1), Func (f2, a2) ->
      let e' = unif e (f1, f2) in
      unif e' (a1, a2)
  | Sym s1, Sym s2 when s1 = s2 -> e
  | _ -> raise Echec
```

I'm getting the message

```
This expression has type ((terme -> terme) * (terme -> terme)) list
but an expression was expected of type (string * terme) list
Type terme -> terme is not compatible with type string
```

I tried `else (v, t) :: List.map (fun (s, t') -> (s, sub v t')) e`
but still nothing

Comment: You may want to explicitly type annotate your functions in this case with what the types are _supposed to be_. That would help us and you determine where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested errors:
The first one is:

```
23 |       else (v, t) :: List.map (fun (t1, t2) -> (sub v t1, sub v t2)) e
                                                                          ^
Error: This expression has type (string * terme) list
       but an expression was expected of type (terme * terme) list
       Type string is not compatible with type terme
```

The second one is:

```
23 |       else (v, t) :: List.map (fun (t1, t2) -> (sub v t1, sub v t2)) ...                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type ((terme -> terme) * (terme -> terme)) list
       but an expression was expected of type (string * terme) list
       Type terme -> terme is not compatible with type string
```

The first error means that you using the value of `e` in an inconsistent way, thus you should check that you using `e` with consistent type within your code. For instance, you might ask yourself:

- What is the type of `e`?
- What is the type of `t1` and `t2` in
  `fun (t1, t2) -> (sub v t1, sub v t2)`?

The second error means that you then using the resulting list in a inconsistent way too. This time, you should look at both the context and how construct the list:

- What is the type of `(v,t)`?
- What is the type of `sub v t2`?
- In particular, what is the type of `sub` (for instance what is the arity of `sub`) ?

After answering all those questions, the location of contradictions within your code should be clearer.